# Can you get two Turkish e-Visa Single Entry Visas within a one month period?

Tags: visas, us-citizens, turkey, pakistani-citizens, istanbul

My wife and I are travelling to Istanbul. She has a Pakistani passport and a green card for the US, so we were able to get single entry visa for her. But the issue is that we are planning to travel from Istanbul to Dubai and would like to stop on both ways to Istanbul.

So the real question is: can we get a single entry visa two times in the same month?

Kindly let me know as everyone has failed to give an answer including Turkish Embassy and Turkish Airlines!

Answer (score 1):

> So the real question is: can we get a single entry visa two times in the  same month?

**Yes.** There is no such restriction listed on the [eVisa](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/) website. You can apply for the second visa as soon as you are out of Turkey. The only restriction is the famous **90 days out of 180** rule.

Focus on the last sentence of this Q&A.

> **The duration of 90-day-stay on my e-Visa expired and I have come back to my country timely. How many days should be passed until I reapply?**
>
> If the duration of 90-day-stay on your e-Visa expired within 180 days as of your first entry date, you can reapply for an e-Visa 180 days later starting from the first entry date. If you spent some part of the duration of 90-day-stay on a multiple entry e-Visa within 180 days as of your first entry date and the rest expired after 180 days elapsed as of the first entry date, it is possible to reapply for an e-Visa. Anyway, please keep in mind that you may stay in Turkey up to 90 days in every 180 days starting from the first entry date.

[eVisa FAQ](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/info/)